# How to remove no data values from merged raster using rioxarray?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, gis, raster, no-data

I have a collection of raster stored in a directory. They are rasters of glaciers in same region. When I remove no data using `rioxarray.where` method on individual rasters it works. But when I use this method on the `merged` product generated using `rioxarray.merge.merge_arrays` method, it does not remove the no data value (which is -9999). Below is the code. I apologize that I was not able to provide a reproducible example.

```
import rioxarray as rxr
from rioxarray import merge
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r'ice_thickness_pandit/*.tif'
files = glob.glob(path)
files

elements = []
for item in files:
    elements.append(rxr.open_rasterio(item))

merged = merge.merge_arrays(elements, nodata=-9999)

merged = merged.where(merged != -9999, drop = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and was able to fix it by using the where command on the input data arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rioxarray as rxr
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = '/path/to/files/'
file1 = 'file1.dat'
cube1 = xr.open_dataarray(path+file1,engine='rasterio')
cube1_masked = cube1.where(cube1 != 0)
cube1.close()
file2 = 'file2.dat'
cube2 = xr.open_dataarray(path+file2,engine='rasterio')
cube2_masked = cube2.where(cube2 != 0)
cube2.close()

#%%
from rioxarray import merge
ds = [
    cube1_masked,
    cube2_masked,
]
merged = merge.merge_arrays(ds, nodata=np.nan)


merged_arr1 = merged[0,:,:]
merged_arr2 = merged[1,:,:]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,4))
merged_arr1.plot(ax=axes[0], add_colorbar=False)
merged_arr2.plot(ax=axes[1], add_colorbar=False)
plt.draw()
```